# Get content of an HTML Com Object in Powershell

Tags: html, powershell, powershell-5.0

I seem to be missing something really basic here and I can't figure it out the way to get content of an HTML file when using Powershell. My initial mission is:

- Open an HTML file in the local directory.
- Find an element with a specific Id.
- **Change** its innerHTML.
- **Save the HTML file** under the same name.

---

Here's how I get the HTML file.

```
Add-Type -path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.mshtml.dll"
$html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$content = Get-Content -Path "test.html" -Raw
$html.IHTMLDocument2_write($content)
```

Next, I find a span element and change its content. When I check with `echo $html.getElementById('versionNumber').innerHTML` before and after the line below. The element indeed changed.

```
echo $html.getElementById('versionNumber').innerHTML  #Result: v1.0
$html.getElementById('versionNumber').innerHTML = "v.$VersionNumber"
echo $html.getElementById('versionNumber').innerHTML  #Result: v1.1
```

The last thing I want to do is save the newly changed HTML file, which I stuck. If the method getElementId works, the HTML should have saved its entire content somewhere but I cannot find the way to extract it.

```
$html | Out-File test.html -Force   #Override the old file
```

`$html` returns all the information about the object, not the content :( `html.body` or `html.body.outerHTML` obviously won't fit as I want to get the entire file. `$html.all`

Example result returned by `$html`

```
Script                            : System.__ComObject
all                               : System.__ComObject
body                              : System.__ComObject
activeElement                     : 
images                            : System.__ComObject
applets                           : System.__ComObject
links                             : System.__ComObject
forms                             : System.__ComObject
anchors                           : System.__ComObject
...
```

My Powershell version is 5.1.

Comment: `$html.documentElement.outerHTML | Set-Content 'test.html' -Force`?

Comment: This one is weird too. My original HTML is a component, not a full one. The above line adds html, head, body tags and even changes old tags, remove `"` of attributes, etc. I think it relates back to `IHTMLDocument2_write`, anyway I found a workaround that... does not use Powershell at all. Gulp and gulp-html-replace.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested the script below and it works.

```
$VersionNumber = "1.1"
Add-Type -path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.mshtml.dll"
$html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$content = Get-Content -Path "test.html" -Raw
$html.IHTMLDocument2_write($content)

echo $html.getElementById('versionNumber').innerHTML  #Result: v1.0
$html.getElementById('versionNumber').innerHTML = "v$VersionNumber"
echo $html.getElementById('versionNumber').innerHTML  #Result: v1.1
$content = $html.documentElement.outerHTML


$content | Out-File "test.html" -Force   #Override the old file
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but I tried this one before. Tags in the result are missing `"`. For example, `<element id=myid></element>`. Strange...

Comment: @LamLe any solution for missing quotes?